# how do I search a multidimentional array for a value on the same level?

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I have a large multidimensional array in which I need to search for a certain value and retrieve a sibling value.

If I search for a value of `29`, I need to make sure that this belongs to a key of `id`.  Once this is found, I need the value of the `label` key. Both of these keys belong to the same nested array.

eg:

```
[26]=>
array(54) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "29"
  ["label"]=>
  string(13) "Special Notes"
```

In this example, I search for 29, which belongs to an `id`, return the value of `label` which is `Special Notes`

In addition to this, it does get a little more complicated..

If the value I am searching for contains a `decimal`, this also belongs to the key `id`, however it is mentioned in multiple places.  The `grandparent` key that it belongs to must be `inputs` and therefore once verified, retrieve the value of label (which is a sibling of id).

eg:

```
["inputs"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "12.1"
      ["label"]=>
      string(4) "Name"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "12.2"
      ["label"]=>
      string(5) "Price"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "12.3"
      ["label"]=>
      string(8) "Quantity"
    }
  }
```

In this example, if I search for `12.1` it will return `Name` - ensuring that all this belongs to `inputs`

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem with this question is that it's so specific that the only answer that someone can give is to actually solve the entire thing for you. This is a complex programmatic problem, and programming is all about solving problems, so don't give it to someone else! However, here's a hint - use object oriented programming instead of trying to traverse a big, complex array. Use the composite pattern, for example, to be able to retain links between parent and child elements.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example here. Maybe it will help...

```
$search_val = "12.1";   // value to search for
foreach($inputs as $key=>$value){
   foreach($value as $keyassoc=>$val){
         if($keyassoc=="id"){
            if($val==$search_val){
                echo "found: ".$inputs[$key]["label"];
            }
         }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just filter out your array instead

```
$inputs = array(
        0 => array("id" => "12.1","label" => "Name"),
        1 => array("id" => "12.2","label" => "Price"),
        2 => array("id" => "12.3","label" => "Quantity"));


$s =  "12.1" ; // what you want
$input = array_filter($inputs,function($v)use($s){ return $v['id'] == $s;});
var_dump($input);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => string '12.1' (length=4)
      'label' => string 'Name' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not getting your point wrong than this will help you:-

```
 function searchLabel($inputs,$search)
    foreach($inputs as $input){
      if($input['id']==$search){
      return $input['label'];
      }
    }
    $label = searchLabel($inputs,12.1);
```